# is it grammatically correct to use "Go" as a noun?

Tags: phrase-meaning, grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

I saw this sentence "So we are a go?". I understand what he meant by that, but is it a correct English  or some informal usage ?

as mention here [How can I make a noun out of a verb? "Go"](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/how-make-noun-from-verb-go-456288)

"Go" use as a verb. Example: I go to school.

"Go" use as a noun. Example: "I have a go" or "It's my go."

So "go" is used both as a verb and noun.

Comment: Yes, "go" is a noun meaning "attempt".

Comment: Yes, it can be both. One idiom springs to mind: "Ed is very active; he's always on the go"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "go" is, in formal English, only a verb.  But it's evolving. In informal speech "go" can be a noun (as in your example) or even an adjective: "Are we go on system 7?"  I checked a few dictionaries and they all seem to agree with this.